# ionic - Can't resolve all parameters for service

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a IncomeTempService:

```
import {incomeService} from "./income.service";

export class incomeTempService {
  private incomeTmp: {value: number, usage: string, date: string};

  private value = null;
  private usage = null;

  constructor(private IncomeService: incomeService){

  }

  setValue(val){
    this.value = val;
  }

  setUsage(usg){
    this.usage = usg;
  }

  setDate(dat){
    this.incomeTmp = {value: this.value, usage: this.usage, date: dat};
    this.IncomeService.addIncome(this.incomeTmp);
  }
}
```

And this is my incomeService:

```
export class incomeService{

  private income: {value: number, usage: string, date: string}[] = [];

  addIncome(Income: {value: number, usage: string, date: string}){
    this.income.push(Income);
  }

  getIncome(){
    return this.income.slice();
  }
}
```

The reason I have an IncomeTempService is because the data will get passed step by step, not all together at once. Since I'm new to ionic, it seemed that this is the best way to pass the data step by step to build a complete object.

So my problem is, when I access the ionic serve interface on http://localhost:8100/
it says the following:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auIv8.png)

Comment: did you set `IncomeService` as a provider in a module?

Comment: Yes I did @SurajRao

Comment: Both classes need to be tagged @Injectable() (this isn't entirely true, but it's good practice) and both need to be provided in the same scope.

Comment: @bryan60 I needed to tag both as Injectable. Solved the problem for me, thanks!

Comment: the truth is that you only need to tag the one that you're injecting stuff into as injectable.  Which sounds backwards but oh well.  This is why it's good practice to put injectable() on every service.

Answer (score 0):

Your `incomeTempService` is simply a class. You must mark it as `@Injectable()` so that Angular knows it has to inject dependencies in it. As a side note, I don't think you should name your classes like that. `IncomeTempService` is the standard.

Comment: Does it still give the same error even with the `@Injectable()` decorator?

Answer (score 0):

@Injectable() decorator SHOULD be added to every service you intend to provide.  It is only NEEDED on services where you are injecting other services into it, which is the opposite of what the decorator seems to imply. What they mean is that "this service is injectable" in the sense that the service is registered with the injector (this is what the decorator really does) and the injector is able to inject into it, thus injectable.

Best practice is just to always add it, there is 0 reason not to, and you won't have any bugs if you decide to inject something into it later.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add @Injectable() in service